# How to insert items in firebase database using different IDs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple database on firebase and basically I'm trying to create a code to insert records on this database. I wanted to insert records like this:

```
id | lat | lng
01 | -55 | -10
02 | -44 | -20
```

each "row" is a new record of a place (latitude and longitude).

I created this example on firebase:

[image]

How can I insert records into this "table" properly??? Because when I created the following code to implement it and I hit the button, it creates a different ID on this table (I'm new to Firebase, I don't get this yet):

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
<form action="" id="newActivity">
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on" runat="server" />  
<input type="hidden" id="city2" name="city2" />
<input type="hidden" id="cityLat" name="cityLat" />
<input type="hidden" id="cityLng" name="cityLng" /> 
<input id="saveForm" name="saveForm" type="submit" value="New Activity">
</form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            document.getElementById('city2').value = place.name;
            document.getElementById('cityLat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
            document.getElementById('cityLng').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
            //alert("This function is working!");
            //alert(place.name);
           // alert(place.address_components[0].long_name);

        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
</script>


<script>



    $(function(){

        var rootRef = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/").ref();
        var placesRef = rootRef.child('places');


        /**
        * Data object to be written to Firebase.
        */
        var data = []


      $('#newActivity').submit(function(event){

          var $form = $(this);
          console.log("submit to Firebase");

          //make the submit disabled
          //$form.find("#saveForm").prop('disabled', true);

          //get the actual values that we will send to firebase
          var cityLatToSend = $('#cityLat').val();

          console.log(cityLatToSend);

          var cityLngToSend = $('#cityLng').val();

          console.log(cityLngToSend);

          //take the values from the form, and put them in an object


          var newActivity = {
            "lat": cityLatToSend,
            "lng": cityLngToSend,
          }


          //put the new object into the data array
          data.push(newActivity);
          console.log(data);
          //send the new data to Firebase

          var newPlaceRef = rootRef.push();
          newPlaceRef.set(data);
          //rootRef.push(data);



          return false;

      })
  })


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In submit function you didn't provide the reference to list.

```
var rootRef = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/").ref();
```

No list provided here.

```
var newPlaceRef = rootRef.push();
  newPlaceRef.set(data);
```

So instead of pushing data to you `places` list application creating a new post reference with an auto-generated id

**Solution**

```
var commentsRef = firebase.database("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/").ref('places');
var newRef = commentsRef.push();
newRef .set(data);
```

hope this helps your fix you issue.
For more information read official documentation.

[Work with Lists of Data on the Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data)

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. I've modified the code. But when it creates a new "place" it creates with this auto-generated id. Isn't possible to create a basica numerical auto-increment id?

Comment: The keys are guaranteed to be unique called push IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('places');
var count = 0;   // will hold the length of places array
var value = { lat: +new Date(), lng: +new Date() / 1000 };   // sample value for lat and lng
firebase
  .database()
  .ref('places')
  .once('value', value => { // get the length of your places array
    if (value.val() == null) count = 0;  // if no places then set it to 0
    else count = Object.keys(value.val()).length;  // otherwise get its length
 // as array items are stored corresponding to their index , Object.keys() can give its length
  })
  .then(() => {
    rootRef.child(count + '').update(value).then( // this will push into your array
      success => {
        console.log('success');
      },
      error => {
        console.log('error');
      }
    );
  });
```

This way you can imitate array.push()

You can also store **places.length** in firebase itself by creating a new field. This way, instead of doing Object.keys() you can use that value. Just keep updating that value after each add/remove to places array.

But you should use push() method.

```
var data = [];
var newActivity = {
        "lat": cityLatToSend,
        "lng": cityLngToSend,
      }
 //data.push(newActivity);      don't do this

rootRef.child('push').push(newActivity)
//This way you can push into get array .
```

Hope you get the idea.

---

Read [this](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html)